# Multilingual solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, multilingual, dynamics-crm-online

Two questions, hopefully with similar answers.

1. I'll be releasing a JavaScript package in my solution where the error messages are to be displayed. The problems is that I'll be targeting German, English and French. Possibly, also a fourth language TBD. What would be the nicest way to resolve this?
2. The label names should **definitely** be localized. Is there a built-in approach to that in CRM 2011? Like a resource table or something like that?

My current solution for (1) is to keep an extra web resource with the strings and distributing a different file for each language. I may rebuild it and distribute all the languages at once and only use a parameter, possibly settable from the GUI if I create a settings-entity. A bit cumbersome.

My current solution for (2) involves a lot of praying and a divine act of some sort. :)

Answer (score 5):

1. To determine current CRM user language dynamically from Javascript you can use `window.USER_LANGUAGE_CODE` (this variable exists on all CRM pages) - for example it will be equal `1033` for English. Than based on that info, you can pick needed string resources from your file.
   Also in forms context there are two predefined functions, which return current Organization language code and current User language code: `Xrm.Page.context.getOrgLcid()` and
   `Xrm.Page.context.getUserLcid()` .
2. If you are talking about custom entities and fields, you can easily add localized display names for them via your solution. You need to edit `customizations.xml` file from your unzipped solution. For each attribute there you will find such XML containing display names:

   ```
     <displaynames>
       <displayname description="Created By" languagecode="1033" />
     </displaynames>
   ```

You can just add new display names for each language you need there.

P.S. If someone interested in different aspects of multilangual support for Dynamics CRM 2011 solutions, I strongly recommend to review this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh670609.aspx), also [here](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/pabloperalta/archive/2011/03/27/how-to-change-the-language-in-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2010/09/24/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-many-base-languages-one-deployment.aspx) is a very helpful reading.

Comment: Please put in some code snippets (not in the text body but as separate code blocks in an edit to your reply). There won't be any last-minute contributions, probably, so you'll be the one taking the bounty. If you want it, that is. I'll just wish to see a more elaborate answer, if that's OK with you. Off the top of my head, I can also think that it could be of value if you at least mention how to change the language. Say that the solution is produced in an English environment and then we want to deploy it to German. Not **just add** German but make it **the only** language in the solution.

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten I have edited it. Actually there is a great msdn article about multilangual solutions. I just don't want to copy it entirely here :)

Comment: I didn't realize that organization and user can have different languages code. I do understand that the client and the server can have that but I always assumed that the organization's language was settable from the menu per user, hence without the need to check his system's language.

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten Organization language is a language which first was installed. Others languages are installed from MUI packs, and then each user can pick one from the list, this will be "user language", but "organization language" will remain the same as first installed. Moreover, solution customization is accessible for particular user only if its current User language is equal to Org language (the language initial install used)

Comment: I guess I've been doing it wrongly, then. One should display labels and other information based on the **user's** language, not the **organization's**, then. How can one change the organization language, then?

Comment: Well, it is impossible to change organization language once organization was created. But if you have some language pack installed on your deployment you can then create new organization with base language another than your initial deployment has.

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten I added some helpful links to my answer about multilingual support.