# CRM 2011 Localization

Tags: localization, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a issue, i had exported my solution of custom entites as a unmanaged, added localization in the customization.xml file, re-imported the solution. After the re-import I tested the localization and it still works.

But for our customer we have to deliver a managed solution. So, I exported the same solution as managed but there are no more Localizations inside the customization.xml.

Are there any ideas why the Localization is missing? (Only in managed solutions)

Comment: Not sure if it's the right information but [here's a discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068562/multilingual-solution) on how to create multi-language solution. Perhaps it can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to use open the default solution and export the translations file , add you localization and import it again.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have now exported the solution as unmanaged and managed and replaced the customization.xml file in the managed solution Folder with the one from the unmanaged.
Seems to work, but I guess this isn't a good approach.